# How to detect a change event on an iOS7 select menu, before the user closes the popup?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios7, mobile-safari

On iOS 7, `<select>` menus in Mobile Safari do not fire a change event until after the user clicks "Done". Are there any other events I can listen for to know when the user's selection has changed?

```
<select onchange="alert('This will not fire until the user clicks Done')">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to determine the new selection value before the user touches "Done".

When the user first touches the `<select>` control, iOS opens a native UI for the select options. This is not DOM. And when the user touches "Done" it sends the new value/index and fires the corresponding event back on DOM.

You can test this. Just setup two events: `onfocus` will setup a timer and continuously poll for `selectedIndex` until `onblur` destroys the timer when "Done" is touched.

```html
<select id="my-select" onfocus="checkSelectedIndex()" onblur="selectDone()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

```js
var timer;
// timer setup on focus
function checkSelectedIndex() {
    timer = window.setInterval(function () {
        console.log('selected index:', document.getElementById('my-select').selectedIndex);
    }, 500); // 2 polls per second
}

// timer cleared on blur
function selectDone() {
    console.log('Selection changed!');
    if (!timer) { return; }
    window.clearInterval(timer);
}
```

With [**this test**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/3Pn4X/), you'll see that even though you change the selected item on the UI; the logged index will not change until after you touch "Done" (which is when the final message is sent to DOM).

So, what you can do is; (with some UX trade off); instead of a `<select>` element, create a custom control which pops up a list of options in a `<div>` or `<ul>`. This way, you'll NOT be triggering the native UI and the user will not leave the DOM. And you'll be able to listen to the events of the menu and clicked items.

Just make sure your control feels mobile-friendly.

#### Enabling Safari Web Inspector for iOS Devices:

1. On iOS device, go to: *Setings » Safari » Advanced* and enable *Web Inspector*.
2. On desktop Safari, go to: *Preferences » Advanced* and check *"Show Developer menu in menu bar"*. A new menu item named "*Develop*" will be added to you Safari menu.
3. Connect your iOS device to your computer via USB.
4. Open the page you want to debug (an external or localhost URL).
5. From the desktop Safari *Develop* menu, select the name of your device and then click the application name in the submenu.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but thanks for confirming it so thoroughly! :)

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Safari on iOS does not fire the `change` event .

Workaround:

using both   **`blur`** and  **`change`**, you can attach a single event handler that unbinds when fired once:  `jQuery has $().one()`

```
$("input[type='select']").one("blur change", function(){  
//will only execute once
  alert('This will fire sure and only once');
});
```

Note: If you need to have the function execute more than once per DOM element ever, you could re-apply it with a `setTimeout`, to avoid the **dual firing**.

Comment: Alas, this does not solve it. If you view http://jsfiddle.net/PcS5E/4/ on an iOS7 device, the event still does not trigger until "Done" is tapped.

Comment: I checked in emulation it worked.
Sorry, I don't have iPhone.

Comment: its stange, because the "select" element, IOS popup , each time the user selects an option, without hitting "done" triggers a change event... which is weird, because the user did not "DONE" it yet. Thats why i usually do for ios, the blur event

Comment: @Miguel - yes! i wonder if something changed between 2014 and 2017. I have a multiple-selection menu bound via knockout, and the change events are definitely firing. As I place checks next to the desired options, the page is updating in the background, prior to closing the popup (tested iPad Mini and iPhone 7 Safari)

Comment: @bkwdesign , not sure if the change is between 2014 and 2017. but the apple opinion is that if the menu state changes then they allow the change to fire, so that they can see the impact of that change in the UI. Imagine that it was a color option, and by checking the colors you could see in real time the color change, personally i think this leads to confusion, because of platform uniformity. That's why you should use the blur which confirms the final state of the value.