# AngularJS 1.5- <select> element displays dropdown at incorrect times (iOS 10 only)

Tags: html, ios, angularjs

As you can infer from the title, this is an interesting & frustrating bug. I have a normal `select` element in an Angular partial with the following code:

```
<select ng-options="availweek.weekNumber as availweek.weekNumber for availweek in availableWeeks | orderBy: 'weekNumber':'reverse'"
  ng-model="selectedWeek.weekNumber" 
  ng-change="viewPrevWeek(selectedWeek.weekNumber)"
  style="color: black">
</select>
```

This element displays a list of numbers (representing weeks) and triggers the `viewPrevWeek` function when one is changed. That function is below- it just passes the week and reloads the partial to reflect data relevant to the selected week:

```
$scope.viewPrevWeek = function (week) {
                if (week <= $scope.totalWeeksAvailable) {
                    $localStorage.active_week = week;
                    $state.reload();
                }
            }
```

My issue is that, on iOS 10 only, if a user changes the selected week via the dropdown (thus triggering `viewPrevWeek`), the dropdown will then pop up on *any* click of *any* button in the rest of the app.

This is precisely as annoying as it sounds- so if a user selects a something in the dropdown and decides to navigate to a new page, the dropdown reappears when clicking to expand the nav. The behavior is as if the dropdown retains focus after selection, so any click in the app also registers as a click on the dropdown, which causes the selector to open.

This only occurs if the week is actually changed- if the user opens the dropdown and selects the choice that was defaulted at page load, this doesn't happen.

I'm at a loss for how to get to the bottom of this- it doesn't occur on Android phones, nor when I use Chrome or other dev tools to force a phone screen resolution on desktop. It occurs on both Safari and Chrome in iOS 10, and doesn't occur in either browser in iOS 9 - so I'm pretty sure this is related to changes in iOS 10.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've solved this one yet, but we had the same problem and came up with a fix.

It seems that iOS 10 has something funky going on in the time between the native dropdown closing and when the code in your ng-change method gets fired. We found that the browser acted like the dropdown was still open and would trigger again when clicking any link, despite our ng-change event firing correctly.

We drew some inspiration from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24056865/542124 and set a timeout inside our method. This allows for iOS to finish closing the native dropdown UI, and finish whatever else it needs to do, before executing our code. In your example, this is how we would approach it;

```
$scope.viewPrevWeek = function (week) {
    if (week <= $scope.totalWeeksAvailable) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $localStorage.active_week = week;
            $state.reload();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

We'll give it a second to finish, show some sort of loading spinner to signify to the user that something is happening, and that should allow enough time to pass to resolve the issue.