# javascript iOS: Programmatically focus textfield from selectfield

Tags: javascript, ios, focus

So here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a form with a textfield, a selectfield and another textfield.

- When you press ENTER in the first textfield, it should focus the
  selectfield.
- When you select a value in the selectfield, it should
  focus the second selectfield.
- When you press ENTER in the third
  textfield, it should focus the first textfield.

Now I know that iOS is very restrictive when it comes to automatically focussing fields, I know that a user
triggered event is needed and that e.g. `setTimeout` will trigger a new event loop which will stop focussing from working and so on.

However, I wrote the following simple vanilla js script (please ignore the duplicate code, this is just a proof of concept), which works fine on a Desktop in any Broswer.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Focus Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doIt() {
            var first = document.getElementById('first')
            var second = document.getElementById('second')
            var third = document.getElementById('third')

            first.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 13) second.focus()
            })

            second.addEventListener('change', function() {
                third.focus()
            })

            third.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 13) first.focus()
            })

            first.focus()
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="doIt()">
    <input id="first" type="text" value="1" />
    <br/>
    <select id="second">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B" selected>B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input id="third" type="text" value="3" />
</body>
</html>
```

You can also try it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/6vj8xyo8/

I tested it on iOS 11.2.5 with Safari, Chrome and Firefox, and here is what happens (the results are the same for every browser):

- On page load, the first textfield should be automatically focused,
  which it is not. That is to be expected, for the reasons I stated
  above. Nothing we can do about that afaik.
- Pressing ENTER in the first textfield leads to the selectfield being
  focussed. So far, so good.
- Select a different value in the selectfield - The native selectfield
  closes, but the third textfield is not focussed.
- Now if you manually focus the third textfield and press ENTER, it
  does focus the first textfield again, like it should.

So it seems that you can programmatically change focus from textfield to selectfield, from textfield to textfield, but NOT from selectfield to textfield. I also verified that the change event is indeed fired.

Am I doing something horribly wrong, or is it just another iOS restriction?

Comment: I am using mac-chrome, working perfectly

Comment: Yes, I am also using a mac, it works perfectly with chrome, firefox and safari. The issue seems to be explicitly iOS, thus only mobile devices like iPhone or iPad are affected.

Comment: try "blur" event, "change" might not work as iphone shows a native control for select which is not part of DOM

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902447/how-to-detect-a-change-event-on-an-ios7-select-menu-before-the-user-closes-the

Comment: When using "blur" instead of "change", it won't fire at all since "blur" is not fired when a value changes .. ? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Looking at the post you referred, it much more looks like that when you touch "Done", an artificial "change" event is dispatched to the DOM. The change event arrives (I confirmed this with an alert message), but its probably not recognised as a user invoked event, which is why you can't set the focus somewhere else. Or so I presume ...

Comment: Make a custom select component, if above post dint work for you, as that is the only option